# How to crop the specific part of image using PaddleOcr Bounding box Co-ordinates

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, ocr, bounding-box, paddle-paddle

Currently I am working on the Vietnamese text detection from the image

So, to detect the text in Image I am using the [PaddleOcr](https://pypi.org/project/paddleocr/) Detection because I need line to line detection. Paddleocr is showing 100% result for that, we can do recognition using PaddleOcr has PaddleOcr didn't trained on Vietnamese it's not giving 100% results.

So, for recognition I am going with [vietocr](https://pypi.org/project/vietocr/) and its showing 100% results but the problem with vietocr is that it is only working when we pass [cropped image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mey7K.jpg) not on [full images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b57ty.jpg).

My plan to crop the Image into multiple by using Bounding box co-ordinates generated from PaddleOcr

I am using PaddleOcr for the text detection

```
Sample Code 

from paddleocr import PaddleOCR,draw_ocr
# Paddleocr supports Chinese, English, French, German, Korean and Japanese.
# You can set the parameter `lang` as `ch`, `en`, `french`, `german`, `korean`, `japan`
# to switch the language model in order.
ocr = PaddleOCR(use_angle_cls=True) # need to run only once to download and load model into memory
img_path = '/content/im1502.jpg'
result = ocr.ocr(img_path, cls=True)
resultss = result
for idx in range(len(result)):
    res = result[idx]
    for line in res:
        print(line)

# draw result
from PIL import Image
result = result[0]
results = result
image = Image.open(img_path).convert('RGB')
boxes = [line[0] for line in result]
txts = [line[1][0] for line in result]
scores = [line[1][1] for line in result]
im_show = draw_ocr(image, boxes, txts=None, scores=None, font_path='/path/to/PaddleOCR/doc/fonts/simfang.ttf')
im_show = Image.fromarray(im_show)
im_show.save('result.jpg')
```

Bounding Box [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7xGC.jpg) and [Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gsq7P.jpg)

```
[[[108.0, 78.0], [289.0, 93.0], [286.0, 131.0], [104.0, 116.0]],
 [[51.0, 230.0], [267.0, 235.0], [266.0, 272.0], [50.0, 267.0]],
 [[17.0, 304.0], [343.0, 304.0], [343.0, 340.0], [17.0, 340.0]]]
```

Recognition with VietOcr

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

from vietocr.tool.predictor import Predictor
from vietocr.tool.config import Cfg
config = Cfg.load_config_from_name('vgg_transformer')

# config['weights'] = './weights/transformerocr.pth'
#config['weights'] = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?id=13327Y1tz1ohsm5YZMyXVMPIOjoOA0OaA'
config['cnn']['pretrained']=False
#config['device'] = 'cuda:0'
config['predictor']['beamsearch']=False

detector = Predictor(config)

img = '/content/im1502.jpg'
img = Image.open(img)
plt.imshow(img)
result = detector.predict(img)
result
```

The result is

```
SẢNH CHUNG
```

So can anyone help me with how to crop the image using paddleocr bounding box coordinates

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, I figured it out. Here boxes are the Bbox from paddelocr

```
box = np.array(boxes).astype(np.int32).reshape(-1, 2)

img = cv2.imread(img_path)
height = img.shape[0]
width = img.shape[1]

mask = np.zeros((height, width), dtype=np.uint8)
New_list = boxes.copy()

for boxs in New_list:
  box=np.array(boxs).astype(np.int32).reshape(-1, 2)
  points = np.array([box])
  cv2.fillPoly(mask, points, (255))
  res = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img,mask = mask)
  rect = cv2.boundingRect(points) # returns (x,y,w,h) of the rect
  cropped = res[rect[1]: rect[1] + rect[3], rect[0]: rect[0] + rect[2]]
```

The cropped will be part of a img of bounding box

Answer (score 0):

For more information, paddleocr has one function to crop image with four coordinates. This function based on green's theory

```
def get_rotate_crop_image(img, points):
# Use Green's theory to judge clockwise or counterclockwise
# use paddleocr rotate image function
# author: biyanhua
d = 0.0
for index in range(-1, 3):
    d += -0.5 * (points[index + 1][1] + points[index][1]) * (
        points[index + 1][0] - points[index][0])
if d < 0:  # counterclockwise
    tmp = np.array(points)
    points[1], points[3] = tmp[3], tmp[1]

try:
    img_crop_width = int(
        max(
            np.linalg.norm(np.array(points[0]) - np.array(points[1])),
            np.linalg.norm(np.array(points[2]) - np.array(points[3]))))
    img_crop_height = int(
        max(
            np.linalg.norm(np.array(points[0]) - np.array(points[3])),
            np.linalg.norm(np.array(points[1]) - np.array(points[2]))))
    pts_std = np.float32([[0, 0], [img_crop_width, 0],
                          [img_crop_width, img_crop_height],
                          [0, img_crop_height]])
    M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(np.float32(points), pts_std)
    dst_img = cv2.warpPerspective(
        img,
        M, (img_crop_width, img_crop_height),
        borderMode=cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE,
        flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    dst_img_height, dst_img_width = dst_img.shape[0:2]
    if dst_img_height * 1.0 / dst_img_width >= 1.5:
        dst_img = np.rot90(dst_img)
    return dst_img
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```